# get-process product version remote computer

Tags: powershell

If I locally do this I get all the information:

```
get-process | select-object name,fileversion,company
```

However, if I do it on a remote computer I only get the process name and all the other fields are blank. Does anyone know why or how to get the same information. I am using a domain admin credential so I should have access to that information.

```
get-process -computername xcomp123 | select-object name,fileversion,company
```

Comment: I see the same thing. You can get the information you want with `Invoke-Command -ComputerName xcomp123 -ScriptBlock { Get-Process } | Select-Object Name, Fileversion, Company`. (Assuming you have PS Remoting configured). Looking at why it doesn't work - it calls out to the .Net Framework `[system.diagnostics.process]::GetProcess()` for local processes and `[system.diagnostics.process]::GetProcess('xcomp123')` for remote processes, so it's outside PowerShell's hands why that doesn't come back with versions remotely. Also if you `gwmi win32_process` locally, version information is not returned.

Comment: You could derive that info from the executablepath property. I'll give an update as I have no time right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
$Computername = 'Remotehost'

$Session = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computername

$process = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -CimSession $Session

$col = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($n in $process){

    $exePath = $null
    $ExeInfo = $null

    $exePath = $n.ExecutablePath -Replace '\\','\\'

    $ExeInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Cim_DataFile -Filter "Name = '$exePath'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    [void]$col.add([PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $n.name
        FileVersion = $ExeInfo.Version
        Company = $ExeInfo.Manufacturer
        PSComputername = $n.PSComputername
    })
}
Remove-Cimsession $session
$col
```

## Update:

I reduced the code to check for one process only. I assert the referencefile having the same name, as the process on the client computers. You might change that for your needs.

You can specify multiple computers at `$computername`, so you do not have to run the code over and over again.

```
#region Reference file

$RefFile = Get-item "\\x123\c$\program files\prog\winagent\file.exe"

#endregion

#region remote file

[string[]]$Computername = 'Remotehost1', 'Remotehost2'
$Processname = $RefFile.Name

foreach ($n in $Computername) {
    $Session = New-CimSession -ComputerName $n
    $process = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -CimSession $Session -Filter "name = '$Processname'"
    $exePath = $process.ExecutablePath -Replace '\\', '\\'
    $ExeInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Cim_DataFile -Filter "Name = '$exePath'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name           = $Processname
            FileVersion    = $ExeInfo.Version
            Company        = $ExeInfo.Manufacturer
            PSComputername = $n
        }
    Remove-Cimsession $session
}

#endregion
```

Comment: I was to compare the version of a process in memory with the file version of the exe to see if they were the same. We have a server product that sends out an agent to the monitored servers. When we upgrade the host server we want to make sure that the remote process is up to date. Here's what I wrote:
      $a = invokecommand -computername x123 -scriptblock { get-
      process } | where-object -filterscript {$_.name -like "123"} | select-
      object fileversion
      $path = '\\x123\c$\program files\prog\winagent\file.exe'
      $b = (dir $path).versioninfo
      compare-object $a $b